# how to create swapchain format DXGI_FORMAT_420_OPAQUE?

Tags: directx-11

Previously, the `swapchain` setting was `RGB32` format, which worked fine.

I want to receive yv12 data and render it.

So I changed `swapChain` format to `DXGI_FORMAT_420_OPAQUE`.

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = { 0 };

swapChainDesc.Width = 0; 
swapChainDesc.Height = 0;
swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_420_OPAQUE;// DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
swapChainDesc.Stereo = false;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0; 
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2; 
swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;


dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(_direct3DDevice, _hwnd, &swapChainDesc, nullptr, nullptr, &_DXGISwapChain);


IDXGISurface *dxgiBackBuffer;
_DXGISwapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgiBackBuffer));
```

Then in `dxgiBackBuffer` I get a `NullReferenceException`.

I think that you can not create back buffer according to `yv12 format`.

Do you know if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supported swapchain formats are those listed as 'display out' in the DXGI [hardware feature levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186615.aspx) format tables. No Direct3D hardware feature level supports a YUV format for display out. You have to perform a YUV to RGB colorspace conversion in a shader somewhere.